# Want to break after if statement, kinda?

Tags: c#, if-statement

So what I am trying to do is test a form textbox for input. Once I click a button, I want it to check if there is any text, if not, I want it to break there and keep prompting a messagebox until the user inputs proper text, and then continue with the program.

```
if (entryName.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name for the entrant");
        }
        if (pickPartner.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please pick a partner to rope with");
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please choose a role");
        }
        else
        {
            if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                headerEntries.Add(entryName.Text);                   
                using (StreamWriter writeRopers = new StreamWriter("headers.txt"))
                {
                    writeRopers.WriteLine(entryName.Text);
                }
                using (StreamWriter writeRopers = new StreamWriter("teams.txt"))
                {
                    writeRopers.WriteLine(entryName.Text + " & " + pickPartner.Text);
                }
                    Debug.WriteLine(entryName.Text + " has been added as a header");
                headerCount = headerCount + 1;
                entryName.Clear();
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

            }
```

Comment: Is the code you have posted within a button click event?

Comment: Add a `return;` after the messagebox line.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ISNullOrWhiteSpace property and if it is true, get the focus on the that textbox like shown here:

```
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entryName.Text))
    {
       entryName.Focus();
       MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name for the entrant");
    }
```

same follow for your other textfields as well.

Comment: Up'd you for the `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` and to help get you going on here. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You could return from the event method if one of your conditions is true.

```cs
    if (entryName.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name for the entrant");
        return;
    }
    if (pickPartner.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please pick a partner to rope with");
        return;
    }
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please choose a role");
        return;
    }
    if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
            headerEntries.Add(entryName.Text);                   
            using (StreamWriter writeRopers = new StreamWriter("headers.txt"))
            {
                writeRopers.WriteLine(entryName.Text);
            }
            using (StreamWriter writeRopers = new StreamWriter("teams.txt"))
            {
                writeRopers.WriteLine(entryName.Text + " & " + pickPartner.Text);
            }
                Debug.WriteLine(entryName.Text + " has been added as a header");
            headerCount = headerCount + 1;
            entryName.Clear();
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a return to force the user to fill out all textbox requirements:

```
if (entryName.Text == "")
{
   MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name for the entrant");
   return;
}
```